# Rails has_one nested resource form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I have something like the following (Sorry for the bad example):

```
resources :houses do
  resource :garage
end
```

How would I generate the form for?

For a has_many it would be something like:

```
 form_for([@house, @garage])
```

This would result in /houses/1/garage/1

If I take the same approach above it would result in /houses/1/garage.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Afaik, you have to enter the path manually for singular resources.

```
form_for [@house, @garage], url: house_garage_path(@house)
```

See this issue on Github: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1769